# SVG icon in twig template

Tags: php, html, svg, twig, icons

I'm struggling with svg icons. I'm creating menu and to do this I have to use several of svg icons. I already know, that if I want to manipulate colour with help CSS (for example when icon is active/hover) I have to use in HTML `<svg>` tag not `<img src="path-to-icon.svg"/>`. 
How can I solve this problem in a nice way?

I don't want use full path of svg in my HTML file, because sometimes it is has a hundred of lines `d="..."` attribute. I try to avoid use `<use xlink:href="path-to-icon.svg" />` as well, because is not supported by IE or Edge browsers.

I can add that I use `.twig` template, so maybe there is a 'PHP' way to add icon.

HTML:

```
  <label id="menuIcon" for="menu" onclick="openNav()">
          {# svg icon #}
  </label>
```

CSS

```
.icon:hover path {
    fill: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would generate my own font file with all the icons used in the application... just like fontawesome or ionicons.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this Craft Function within Twig it may be useful:
https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/functions.html#svg

You can also put your  code into a .twig template and `include` that like you would any other twig file.